# Running RegEx within Google Script If Statement

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I'm using a Google Script to extract values from a column that match my regex, but I can't seem to get my regex variable to work with my if statement. When I set the variable to a string, I have no problem with running my function and getting a response back, but it isn't working with the regex and I'm trying to figure out the issue:

Here is my script:

```
function extractBranded() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var keywords = /ipad dns|dns system/;

    if (data[i][0] == keywords) {
      Logger.log(data[i][0]);
    } else {

    }
  }
```

Google Sheets Data (Queries = Column and Row A1):

```
Queries
dns system
dns systems
ipad dns
ipad dns system
business 101
ipad dns register
dns
```

In theory this should pick up on four of the seven values in my sheet.

I also tried calling a constructor function with `new RegExp()`, but this did not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your RegExp reads as "ipad dn(s|d)ns system", you're missing parenthesis.

Comment: Using `if (data[i][0].match(keywords)) {`, I obtained 5 results: `dns system`, `dns systems`, `ipad dns`, `ipad dns system`, `ipad dns register` - is it what you are looking for? You forgot to call `.match()`. Or `test()`: `if (keywords.test(data[i][0])) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
if (data[i][0].match(keywords)) {
```

Or

```
if (keywords.test(data[i][0])) {
```

You will obtain 5 results:

```
[15-08-31 23:27:52:850 CEST] dns system
[15-08-31 23:27:52:864 CEST] dns systems
[15-08-31 23:27:52:865 CEST] ipad dns
[15-08-31 23:27:52:866 CEST] ipad dns system
[15-08-31 23:27:52:866 CEST] ipad dns register
```

You forgot to call `match()` or `test()` to actually apply your regex.